# ensuring nginx always restarts

Tags: nginx, systemd

the service setup with systemd for file `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`
was set up with a last line in the service block

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
[...]
KillMode=mixed
Restart=always
```

to always restart.
However, this line seems to have disappeared at some point in time.  I seem to recall something about aliases, but the [documentation does not specifically](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) refer to them.

There are multiple users defined on the VPS and it is *possible* the nginx service file got somehow changed after adding a new user. (*possible*, as there was no implicit check immediately after; this is the only event of structural change - with certificate re-issuances - that come to mind)

Is there a way to ensure that the restart service remains stated?

Answer (score 0):

- Nginx rarely crashes, but when it does, this is always an issue in it's code that should be reported.
- Nginx has a built-in mechanism to rotate it's logs, to test the configuration and to **reload it on the fly**.

Thus there's no need to ensure it's restarted when it crashes. You're solving an issue that doesn't exist.